# Смена текста при наведении

Tags: javascript, css

Нужен скрипт, чтобы слово в HTML верстке менялось при наведении. При этом список этих слов брался бы из справочника, неважно как он будет организован, но лучше, чтобы в java скрипте из массива, а не из базы. В идеале, конечно вообще на CSS.  При этом к каждому слово можно задать свой цвет.  То есть у каждого элемента массива два параметра - цвет, слово.

У Лебедева в на сайте похожая вещь в логотипе, но у него там просто цвет играет.

Comment: @Ильяс Билалов, Что вы уже сделали и что не получилось?

Comment: у Лебедева на сайте, если я не ошибаюсь, просто при наведении случайный цвет подставляется.

Comment: обратитесь к Тёме, он за пару месяцев вам сделает.

Comment: я не делал ещё ничего я спрашиваю про скрипт, наверняка похожиц где-то есть, может кому встречался или кто-то знает где искать. Я в js вообще не бум-бум. Только начал изучать html и css.

Comment: Тёма кстати облажался с этим логотипом - для светлых фонов ink не меняется.

Comment: @Ильяс Билалов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Текст и его цвет прописаны в массиве `words_array`. При наведение меняется соответственно и текст и его цвет.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var counter = 0;

            function getWordColor() {
                var words_array = [
                    ["one", "red"],
                    ["two", "yellow"],
                    ["three", "green"]
                ];

                function getCount() {
                    if(counter < (words_array.length - 1)) {
                        counter += 1;
                    } else {
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                    return counter;
                }
                return words_array[getCount()];
            }

            $("#text").hover(function() {
                var word_color = getWordColor();
                $(this).text(word_color[0]);
                $(this).css("color", word_color[1]);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="text">test</span>
</body>
</html>
```

В css содержимое элемента можно менять через правило `content`, а определить правило применяемое к тегу во время наведения на него мыши можно через псевдокласс `:hover`. Например:

```
.class {
   /* Правило по умолчанию */
}

.class:hover {
     /* Правило по наведению курсора */
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое добрый человек)